# Yup validation requiring at least one selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I'm trying to require one of two checkboxes to be selected in a form. The following doesn't seem to work according to the documentation:

```
yearGroups: yup.object().shape({
          primary: yup.bool().when('yearGroups.primary', {
            is: false,
            then: yup
              .bool()
              .oneOf([true], '')
              .required()
          }),
          secondary: yup.bool().when('yearGroups.secondary', {
            is: false,
            then: yup
              .bool()
              .oneOf([true], '')
              .required()
          }),
        }),
```

Comment: Do you have any error message?

Comment: no, I just don't get the validation I require @NearHuscarl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one. See the explanation [here](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/176#issuecomment-367352042):

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  yearGroups: yup.object().shape(
    {
      primary: yup.bool().when("secondary", {
        is: (secondary) => !secondary,
        then: yup.bool().oneOf([true], "At least one needs to be checked")
      }),
      secondary: yup.bool().when("primary", {
        is: (primary) => !primary,
        then: yup.bool().oneOf([true], "At least one needs to be checked")
      })
    },
    [
      ["primary", "secondary"],
      ["secondary", "primary"]
    ]
  )
});
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: This example worked for me. Note that u need to use the dependencies array into the .shape() function. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is some kind of duplication, but here are solutions: using `.test()` function or create your own Method - .`addMethod`

1. `.test` function, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57863852/yup-validation-on-multiple-values)
2. .addMethod function, example [here](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/248)

I am using `.addMethod` in my code, it's more flexible, you can define all params you need. Once you defined it in the file, you can call it everywhere you need.