# React Formik validation by checking values against each other

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm using Formik for data validation and I came across a something that should be very simple to do but I can't figure it out, even after reading the docs and looking at SO for hours.

Basically I have a form where you can submit multiple entries with a start and end date. I'm using yup to validate that the dates are in the correct format, but when I submit, I need the form to check that the dates are NOT overlapping.

The below is an example of the formik values to be submitted with just 2 entries - there could be more:

(for simplicity, I've just put normal dates in, in reality they are in milliseconds)

```
[
    {entryId: 1, startDate: Jan 1 2023 , endDate: Jan 5 2023},
    {entryId:2, startDate Jan 3 2023, endDate: Jan 7 2023}
]
```

In this case, the entries have an overlap between Jan 3 and Jan 5, so the form should show an error on submission.

I've looked into the `validate` functions in the formik docs [docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#validate-values-values--formikerrorsvalues--promiseany) but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

My colleague at work figured it out. As I mentioned in the question I'm using `yup`for the validation schema, and that is what needs to be used to solve this, instead of using formiks validation directly.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57863852/yup-validation-on-multiple-values) post in SO, which hints to the response.

So a `yup` validation schema needs to be created, using the `when` in combination with the `test` methods and passed into Formiks  `validationSchema`:

```
const myValidation = yup.object().shape({
  entries: yup.array().of(
    yup.object().shape({
      entryId: yup.number().required("Id is required"),
      startDate: yup.number().required("Date is required").nullable(),
      endDate: yup.number().when("startDate", (startDate, schema) =>
        schema.test({
          test: function (endDate: number) {
            console.log("THIS", this);
            /*
             inside of 'this' object, all the values inside the form can be
             accessed and custom validation can be build comparing these
             values against each other
            */
           validation code here...
          },
        })
      ),
    })
  ),
});
```